# how to get aggregate from fields in mongoose using node js from another models

Tags: node.js, json, mongoose, aggregate

**I have two models schema** productPerDay and productPerMonth

```
// Model 1 that input data every day
const productPerDay = new mongoose.Schema({
   product : String,
   price : Number,
   month : {
       type : String
       default : () => moment(Date.now()).tz('Asia/Jakarta').locale('id').format('MMMM')
   }
}, {
    timestamps : {
       currentTime: () => moment(Date.now()).tz('Asia/Jakarta').locale('id').format('YYYY-MM-Do LT')
     }
});

//Model 2 That input data every month and get aggregate for total price field from price data model1 that input every day
const productPerMonth = new mongoose.Schema({
    product : String,
    totalPrice : Number,
    month : {
       default : () => moment(Date.now()).tz('Asia/Jakarta').locale('id').format('MMMM')
     }
}, {
    timestamps : {
       currentTime: () => moment(Date.now()).tz('Asia/Jakarta').locale('id').format('YYYY-MM-Do LT')
    }
});
```

**the results I expect are like this**

```
//From Model 1
[
    {
        "product" : "book",
        "price" : 5000,
        "month" : "May"
    },
    {
        "product" : "book",
        "price" : 10000,
        "month" : "May"
    }
    {
        "product" : "pen",
        "price" : 100,
        "month" : "June"
    },
    {
        "product" : "pen",
        "price" : 200,
        "month" : "June"
    }
]

//From Model 2
[
    {
        "product" : "book",
        "month" : "may",
        "totalPrice" : 15000
    },
    {
        "product" : "pen",
        "month" : "June",
        "totalPrice" : 300
    }
]
```

**I try to post and get the result from Model 1 in Nodejs like this**

```
// router to post and get data each day
router.post('/productPerDay', async (req,res) => {
    const product = new ProductPerDayModels({});
    try {
        await ProductPerDayModels.save();
        res.status(201).json(product);
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send(e);
    }
});

router.get('/productPerDay', async (req,res) => {
    try {
        const product = await ProductPerDayModels.find([]);
        res.json(product);
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send(e);
    }
});
```

**I want to get data for totalPrice field in model 2 from every price data filled in Model 1 And the data is added together for every month the same**

```
//router 2 to get and post each month
router.post('/productPerMonth', async (req,res) => {
    const product = new ProductPerMonthModels({
        ...req.body,
        totalPrice : //what should i do here to get totalPrice from price fields in model 1?
    });
    try {
        await ProductPerMonthModels.save();
        res.status(201).json(product);
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send(e);
    }
});

router.get('/productPerMonth', async (req,res) => {
    try {
        const product = await ProductPerMonthModels.find([]);
        res.json(product);
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send(e);
    }
});
```

**Please guide me to resolve this or tell my mistake in resolving it. thank you**

Comment: Checkout $lookup to populate values from other collection

Comment: may you give me some example please?

Comment: How many collections do you have in Mongo?

Comment: i have many .. but i make it two for example to get aggregate